# Open a cmd window and issue multiple commands

Tags: java, cmd, runtime.exec

I have to open (or execute in the background) a cmd window out of my java application. It did this before and it worked totally fine:

```
public String getEnvVar(String envVarName) throws Exception {
    String varName = "%" + envVarName + "%";
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
            new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/C", "echo " + varName}
    );
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream())
    );
    varName = input.readLine();
    process.destroy();
    ...
```

My problem is: I have a different instance of a different class and tried to open a cmd window just the way it is done in the code above:

```
private void execute() {
    try {
        String batchData = batchContent();
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/C", batchData});
        new File(sourceFile).delete();
        new File(sourceFolder).delete();
        process.destroy();
    } catch (IOException ie) {

    }
}
```

But this doesn't work...I used google to figure out why, couldn't find a real reason for this.

Even

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "cd c:\\temp"});
```

does not change into the temp folder (which i created beforehand for testing reasons)

What's wrong?

EDIT//

I now tried:

```
private void upload() {
    try {
        //Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(batchDataFile);
        //Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C " + batchDataFile);
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C " + "\"" + batchDataFile + "\"");
        //new File(sourceCodeFile).delete();
        //new File(batchDataFile).delete();
        //new File(sourceCodeFolder).delete();
        process.destroy();
    } catch (IOException ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I additionally tried to run the generated batch skript without the Java app, it works as intended

Comment: It's bad style to work with OS command line from java. Consider writing .bat script which launches your java application.

Comment: there might be an IOException but there is no logging in the catch. It is good practice to log exceptions in the least or propagate.

Comment: I am not trying to lunch a java application ... i am tyring to execute a batch script from within my java application. And there is also no IOException. I had logging enabled for testing. No exception, no execution. But a simple println is displayed, it isn't dead code.

Comment: I understand that you're trying to work with OS commands from java. It's a bad style. Write batch script instead.

Comment: have you tried to run on a separate thread?

Comment: Okay, i changed my code and my batchData is now stored in a file. But the whole thing is still not working...i edited the post above with some additional Code. Whats the use of running it on a different Thread?

Comment: Okay i am now one step further. I added a `process.waitFor();` directly after the cmd comand. i can now at least see something happen. Sadly the called program crashes and the wait for returns a '1'. If i run the batch script without the java app it is still running without any crashes.

Comment: Last update for today: Even if i do `while(triue){}` after the initialized process my executed programm crashes. This is so strange i am completely helpless right now. Hopefully some of you has a really brilliant idea why this is happening

Comment: Update: Resolved my issue. My code is working as intended the program crah is caused by Windows/my Laptop itself. It works fine on other people's laptop